# CallbackQueryHandler reply message instead of edit message - Python Telegram Bot

Tags: python, callback, bots, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm developing a bot using [python telegram bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot)

I would like to be able to send a reply message from a **InlineKeyboardButton** instead of having to edit the current message.

```
def callback(update, context):

    # this works (but I don't want to edit the current message but sending a new one)
    update.callback_query.edit_message_text("response")
    
    # this unfortunately does not work
    update.message.reply_text("response") # None has no attribute 'reply_text'


...


updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(self.callback))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only one of the optional attributes of [`Update`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.update.html) will be present at a time. If the update from pressing an inline button, then `update.callback_query` is present, but `update.message` is not. However, [`update.callback_query.message`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.callbackquery.html#telegram.CallbackQuery.message) *may* be present, depending on whether or not the message with the inline button was sent by the bot itself or via inline mode. If it is present, you can also access it via the convenience property [`update.effective_message`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.update.html#telegram.Update.effective_message).

---

Dislaimer: I' currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`

Comment: like a charm, thanks :)